# Group by is throwing error in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I want to group by service name to all my record and I am using this query in SQL Server but it's throwing an error

```
select max(c.service_id) as service_id, a.ser_id, b.UserID, 
    SQRT(POWER(69.1 * ( @latitude - b.Latitude),2) + POWER(69.1 * ( b.Longitude - @longitude ) * COS(b.Longitude / 57.3), 2)) as distance,
    c.service_name
from aspnet_bawe_services a 
left join aspnet_user_account b on a.bawe_id = b.UserID 
left join aspnet_services_app c on a.ser_id = c.service_id 
group by c.service_name
```

Error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure app_service_list, Line 24
>   Column 'aspnet_bawe_services.ser_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory: The only columns you can select are `service_name` or other columns contained inside an aggregate function like `MAX()`.  And since you never showed us sample input and output data, the correct query can only be guessed.

Comment: Please provide a question that is answerable.  It is impossible to figure out what you want based on the query you provided as it is mostly composed of illegal SQL.

Comment: Any reason you're doing geography calculations by hand rather than using the built in support for `geography`?

Comment: **Simple rule**: if you use `GROUP BY`, then **every** column in your statement must *either* be in the `GROUP BY` clause, *OR* it must be handled by an aggregating function like `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` etc. -- **EVERY** one of them - no exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should grouping every column which not in aggregate function, or use aggregate function for those columns

first like this

```
select  max(c.service_id) as service_id, a.ser_id ,b.UserID,SQRT(POWER(69.1 * ( @latitude - b.Latitude),2) + POWER(69.1 * ( b.Longitude - @longitude ) * COS(b.Longitude / 57.3), 2)) as distance,c.service_name
    from aspnet_bawe_services a 
    left join aspnet_user_account b on a.bawe_id=b.UserID 
    left join aspnet_services_app c on a.ser_id=c.service_id 
    group by c.service_name, a.ser_id,b.UserID,b.Latitude,b.Longitude
```

or second like this

```
    select  
    max(c.service_id) as service_id, 
    max(a.ser_id), max(b.UserID), 
    sum(SQRT(POWER(69.1 * ( @latitude - b.Latitude),2) + POWER(69.1 * ( b.Longitude - @longitude ) * COS(b.Longitude / 57.3), 2))) as distance,
    c.service_name
from 
    aspnet_bawe_services a 
left join 
    aspnet_user_account b on a.bawe_id = b.UserID 
left join 
    aspnet_services_app c on a.ser_id = c.service_id 
group by 
    c.service_name
```

Comment: I already checked your query and it throws "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure app_service_list, Line 24
Column 'aspnet_user_account.Latitude' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure app_service_list, Line 24
Column 'aspnet_user_account.Longitude' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"

Comment: what do you want ? grouping Latitude? or choose from Latitude s maximum or minimum?

Comment: evere service_id can has many Latitude, you are grouping service_id but don't do anything with Latitude, what do you want choose maximum? or group it?

Comment: i want group by service name and i also need distance base on latitude and longitude that i am using in query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144517/discussion-between-pankaj-sharma-and-vecchiasignora).

Comment: i have changed second query in my answer try it and answer me

Comment: Thanks @Vecchiasignora solution work  for me. what changes you done? i think query is same.

Comment: Thanx you save my day really appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 1):

When you `group by`, it means that you want to ,,compress" multiple rows, which coressponds to one value in column, which you want to group by. Since ALL columns (exept the one you are grouping by) must be contained in an aggregating function (like `max` or `sum`, etc.), even if it's not necessary! Because SQL doesn't know what you might know :) So, you have to put `a.ser_id` in some aggregate function.

Comment: I also used this query "select max(c.service_id) as service_id, max(a.ser_id) as ser_id,max(b.UserID) as bawe_id,SQRT(POWER(69.1 * ( @ latitude - b.Latitude),2) + POWER(69.1 * ( b.Longitude - @longitude ) * COS(b.Longitude / 57.3), 2)) as distance ,c.service_name from aspnet_bawe_services a left join aspnet_user_account b on a.bawe_id=b.UserID left join aspnet_services_app c on a.ser_id=c.service_id group by c.service_name"

Answer (score 0):

If you want use group by then all the columns selected should be in aggregate functions and if you do not want to apply any aggregate function on those columns then they must be in group by clause.
In your case you should try :

```
select  max(c.service_id) as service_id, a.ser_id ,b.UserID,SQRT(POWER(69.1 * ( @latitude - b.Latitude),2) + POWER(69.1 * ( b.Longitude - @longitude ) * COS(b.Longitude / 57.3), 2)) as distance,c.service_name
from aspnet_bawe_services a 
left join aspnet_user_account b on a.bawe_id=b.UserID 
left join aspnet_services_app c on a.ser_id=c.service_id 
group by c.service_name,**a.ser_id,b.UserID**
```

Or you can just remove **a.ser_id,b.UserID** if you don't want this

Or if you want these columns then you must apply group by or any aggregate function on a.ser_id,b.UserID else they will not work as your server looks in strict mode. So if you want to run you query as it is then you have to disable strict mode on your data base . If you are using MYSQl then this link might help you https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-disable-mysql-strict-mode/

Comment: No i want that also.

Comment: Than you must apply group by or any aggregate function on a.ser_id,b.UserID else they will not work as your server looks in strict mode. So if you want to run you query as it is then you have to disable strict mode on your data base . If you are using MYSQl then this link might help you https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-disable-mysql-strict-mode/